# How to open app from Twitter for iOS WebView on iOS 9

Tags: ios, twitter, ios9, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

My question pertains to deeplinking from a link shared on Twitter into my app on iOS 9.

Prior to iOS 9, using an app's URL scheme in a redirect would take the user from Twitter into that app. Now, as described [here](http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes) (I'm assuming this is the reason it no longer works), URL schemes for other apps can not be opened by Twitter. It still works on the Facebook app for iOS 9, and I assume the difference is Twitter uses `canOpenUrl:`, which now returns `NO`.

This led me to try [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12), but with my current implementation these *only* work in Safari.

Has anyone found a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Add Twitter scheme to your Info.plist.

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>twitter</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: Universal links didn't work with this setting. Can someone else confirm this? However, what works is the "Open" button inside Twitter Cards: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/app

Comment: @SukruK Isn't this for the other direction though? As in, opening Twitter from my app? I'm asking about going from Twitter _to_ my app. Incidentally I already have Twitter in the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` because I do want to open Twitter from my app. 

@Hugo Recently I've only ever had a "download" button on my Twitter cards, no "open" button.

Comment: @MichaelBiehl currently I see a "Download" button if the app is not installed and after installation I see a "Open" button. Nevertheless, it's pretty lame that the Twitter App don't follow the current standards like the FB App.

Comment: @MichaelBiehl now that I updated to the latest version of Twitter App, the Twitter card button always show "Download on App Store" regardless of having the app installed or not. However, if the app is installed, tapping on the button takes me to my app (not the app store). The in-app web view doesn't open mobile deep links. The popup asking if the user wanted to open the app is gone.